# Is excluding i tag from global font family css in order to use fa-fa possible?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I've been using global css for font-family until I got to footer where I used fa-fa icons which seems to not be working with this piece of code

```
  html *
{
   font-size: 1em !important;
   color: #000 !important;
   font-family: Arial !important;
}
```

so I was wondering if there is a trick to exclude html i tag from this global css?

Comment: Why on earth would you use this selector, and with `!important` no less

Comment: Your problem (as exampled by your `!important`s) is specificity. If you say "not `<i>`" then you are in effect not styling that element, but that element will take the style of its parent, which your `*` tag **will** style, so in effect, what you apply to any parent of `<i>` will apply to to `<i>` with this CSS. What you need to do instead is *replace* the above, for `<i>` elements.

Comment: You should remove your `!important`s and add [**specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) to your class rules. And then add a **specific** rule for `i` elements.